# Related associations in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database-design

### The stage:

Let's say I have models defined as follow:

```
class Client < AR:Base
  has_one :driver_profile, class_name: 'Driver'
  has_many :races
end

class Driver
  # attribute :dob

  belongs_to :client
  has_and_belongs_to_many :teams
end

class Race
  # attribute :date

  belongs_to :client
  has_and_belongs_to_many :drivers
end
```

Logic behind this is: each client registered on the page is able to register a number of different races, each team can have multiple drivers. However each customer is a driver as well and by default it is to be assigned to each of his teams. To achieve this I have overriden Team `drivers` reader (I'm using `andand` gem):

```
def drivers
  association = super
  driver_profile = client.andand.driver_profile
  if !driver_profile || driver_profile.new_record? || association.include? driver_profile 
    association << client.driver_profile
  end
  association
end
```

This works pretty well, however is not as pretty as I would like it to be (and it makes an extra db call each time I call this method).

### The problem

I have a pretty huge multistepped form for all the models. In first two steps user can edit his personal info (on Client model), his driver_profile and his initial race. On a later step he can add any number of drivers to his race, however drivers date of birth needs to be verified against race date (must be at least 21).

The problem is, that this validation does not fall onto a driver model, as a driver can be valid for one race and is not valid for a second race. Hence this is a race issue rather than a drivers. I wrote validation like this (on a Race model):

```
validate :drivers_at_least_21

def drivers_at_least_21
  error = false
  drivers.each do |driver|
    if driver.age_at(start) < 21
      driver.errors.add(:dob, :too_young)
      error = true
    end
  end
  errors.add(:driver, :invalid) if error
end
```

This works in most of the cases, however since `client.driver_profile` and `drivers` are completely different associations, errors added to a driver in `drivers` are not added to `client.driver_profile` and are not being displayed on the nested fields for driver_profile (first pages). I've managed to overcome it using:

```
(drivers + Array.wrap(client.andand.driver_profile)).uniq(&:object_id).each do |driver|
```

This is however extremely hacky, ugly and generally terrible, hence this is a perfect moment to assume that the models design is wrong.

### The question

How would you redesign database models and associations for this? I thought a number of solutions so far:

1. To use union to define drivers on the race. This would be definitively the best option if only union method returned querable AR relation.
2. Creating association like `other_drivers` and define method `drivers` to sum drivers and driver_profile. This way I wont be able to query drivers results.
3. 'Hack' drivers association's target method to add driver_profile to it - this however won't be persisted in resulted scopes.

Answer (score 0):

I was wondering, what about converting your drivers association to a polymorphic one?

I'm thinking about something like this (note: I used `racers` in order to avoid confusion with `Driver` instances):

Migration:

```
# RaceRacer migration
class CreateRaceRacers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :race_racers do |t|
      t.references :race, index: true
      t.integer :racer_id
      t.string :racer_type

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Models:

```
# RaceRacer model
class RaceRacer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :race
  belongs_to :racer, polymorphic: true
end

# Race model
class Race < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :race_racers
  has_many :driver_racers, through: :race_racers, source: :racer,
           source_type: :Driver
  has_many :customer_racers, through: :race_racers, source: :racer,
           source_type: :Customer

  # Unfortunately ActiveRecord doesn't support has_many on a polymorphic
  # association without :source_type, so we need to define a method
  def racers
    race_racers.map(&:racer)
  end
end

# Driver model
class Driver < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :race_racers, as: :racer
  has_many :races, through: :race_racers
end

# Customer model
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :race_racers, as: :racer
  has_many :races, through: :race_racers
end
```

`Race.first.racers` is a `map` on `race_racers`, so the errors on `Driver` and `Customer` instances should be ok

Comment: Could you give some mere details on how to do this?

Comment: Answer updated; if you provide the query that suits your needs and the database you are using I can help you further

Comment: Thanks. The problem with this approach I see is that I need to validate models which has been changed as well, including non-persistent records. I don't need to validate db entires, since they are always to be correct.

Comment: Polymorphic associations came me to mind, so I updated the answer

Comment: Hmmm. Quite like the idea, however the racer method introduces n+1 problem (likely can be fixed with include) and returns non-querable object.

Comment: Yes, the `racers` method is the problem of this approach; it's a pity Rails doesn't support `has_many :through` on polymorphic sources without `:source_type`, they would be very useful

Comment: It would require union associations to implement those. I know they are currently working on them right now (last time I've checked there was a pull request pending), so who knows, maybe soon.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your situation correctly:

I don't think you should be using the `validation` mechanism to qualify drivers for races. An 18 year old driver is a *valid* `Driver`, but he's just not *qualified* for certain races. I think you should be asking each `Race#driver_not_qualified_reasons(driver)`.

You'd ask `Race` each time a driver is about to be added whether or not the driver is qualified. When looking up a `Driver`'s profile, you would then iterate through all the future races he wants to attend to ask each `Race`:

```
def Driver.get_qualification_errors
  self.races.starting_after(Time.now).map do |race|
    race.driver_not_qualified_reasons(self)
  do
end
```